# Installed TensorFlow successfully, but after invoking python on the shell & importing it, it says tensorflow command not found

Tags: software-installation, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow successfully, but after invoking `python` on the shell and importing it, it says `tensorflow command not found` .

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is installed correctly, but it must be run from the python3 interpreter and you tried to run it from the python interpreter instead.

Start the python3 interpreter with `python3` and run the following line of code to import tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

If `import tensorflow as tf` doesn't return an error message that means that is has been imported successfully. Now that you have installed TensorFlow you may want to run the example code from [TensorFlow 2 quick start for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) tutorial to start using it. The example code also requires Keras deep learning framework.

```
sudo apt install python3-keras # 18.04 and later
```